# iOS Save in-app purchase data and deal with jailbreak

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I 've created apps that use in-app purchase and everything's OK. Now suppose that the device is jailbroken and without access to the internet (so I can't verify the store receipt) and the  user finds the file I 've saved the purchase information and manipulates it.

How can I deal with this situation? Is there an apple-defined way? Or should I use encryption (along with the process of getting the ERN)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, jailbroken devices can be ignored. If someone **really** wants to pirate your in-app purchase on a jailbroken device, he/she will be able to.

Yes, you can make it harder, but is it worth the effort? Wouldn't you profit more (by getting more sales) from adding a few features instead and making your app more attractive?

Also, Apple is hard at work at making the iPhones difficult to jailbreak, and right now, it looks as they'd be fairly successful doing so.

No, there is no Apple-defined way as far as I know. Yes, you could use encryption with the device ID as key (or something along those lines). You could also use the iOS keychain instead of a file to store your purchase information.

Answer (score 0):

I use is my own "trick" to deal with this problem.

First i choose 2 different big prime numbers (5-6 digits should do) and multiply them and add 1.
One of them is "master prime" and the other one is dependent of the item bought in store.

(master_prime * prime)+1;

The resulting number is a 9~15 digit number.

I save that in 2 different places in my app (like a [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) into a file and in NSUserDefaults).

This is what happens when the user buys something from store.

When i start the app i do a few checks :

- if the 2 files have the same numbers
- if the result of prime = (9-digit number/master_prime - 1) is prime
- if the prime has a certain property ( usually sum of the digits is equal to a certain number)

If any of those aren't true then i try to connect to the internet to restore purchase. If i can't...bye bye purchase (until i can connect to the internet again...ofc).

To optimize this..you could check the first condition...if it's not true no need to check for the others.

I gave a number like this to one of my friends to crack it..and it took him ~ 5 hours to do it with 1 7 digit number as master prime and 5 digit number as store variable prime. And this is because he knew what he was doing...if you don't know how to come up with those numbers it would take days or even months.

You can improve upon this with 3 primes instead of 2..or bigger numbers...or each prime has different property.